# Remove column in index view using active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Here I have used active admin with rails 6. consider Index view has nearly 5 to 10 columns. If I want to customize column means should do like this.

`index do
  column :name
  column :description
  column :released_year
  column :director
  column :producer
  column :artist
  actions
end`

Ok. no problem.

Unless, My model has nearly 50 column. I want to show 48 columns. At that time I want to describe these 48 columns should show. My question is, can we have to remove those 2 columns from index view, instead of writing necessary column. Like,

`index do
  remove_column :created_at
  remove_column :updated_at
end`

Comment: Why do you want to remove the timestamp column? If you want to remove columns write a migration file to remove column.

Comment: @SantoshAryal Thanks for commenting. I have mentioned created at and updated at columns  for example. You can consider those columns used for some other purposes. But at index view they are not necessary.

Comment: Did you try removing the columns?

Comment: They don't want to remove the column from the database, just not display them on the index

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your model is called Model try:

```
attributes_to_display = Model.new.attributes.keys - ['attribute_1', 'attribute_2']
index do
  attributes_to_display.each do |attribute|
    column attribute.to_sym
  end
  actions
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (`MyModel` beeing your Model):

```
  exclude_columns = [:attribute_to_exclude_1, :attribute_to_exclude_2]
    

  index do
    selectable_column
    ModelName.attribute_names.each  do |clmn|
      column clmn if not exclude_columns.include? clmn.to_sym
    end
    actions
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

resource_columns handles associations for you, so:

```
attributes = active_admin_config.resource_columns - [:attribute_1, :attribute_2]
index do
  selectable_column
  id_column
  attributes.each do |attribute|
    column attribute
  end
  actions
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solution worked for me but it was not showing the associated object with link & just showing the associated object id. In my case, I just have only one associated object so I handled it that way

```
index do
    columns_to_exclude = ["url"]
    (Feature.column_names - columns_to_exclude).each do |c|
      if c != "car_model_id"
        column c.to_sym
      else
        column "car_model".to_sym
      end
    end
```

In this way, your associated object behaviour is preserved & you can go to the parent object from the link.